# Eclipse opens compiled python instead of source code on breakpoint

Tags: python, eclipse, debugging, pydev

I am having some trouble with my Eclipse debugger. Every time I set a breakpoint on Python source files, when the breakpoint is hit Eclipse opens up the associated pyc compiled file.

Below are a few things I have tried:

- Creating a new Eclipse project with the code
- Deleting all settings files within the code
- Switch to a new workspace
- Re-install eclipse and PyDev completely.

The problem persists. I don't know what could possibly be causing this. The issue only occurs when a breakpoint is set. However, that renders breakpoints useless in Eclipse.

This issue only began after I tried to set up Visual Studio for Python development. In Visual Studio this issue does not occur.

Comment: I was not aware that python compiled code, are you trying to set breakpoints in your own code or third party code? I would also  right click on the eclipse project you have your breakpoints in and see what is on the source path.

Comment: Yes, Python source files are .py and compiled files are .pyc. I have checked the Breakpoints window and I can see they are pointing to the .py file. When I disabled all breakpoints the problem goes away.  It always puts the cursor on line 1 on the pyc version of the py file I set the breakpoint on. The Debug window has a thread stack which points directly to the .pyc file. The Breakpoints window correctly shows the py file.

Comment: Got ya, I love Eclipse but the python tools are not the best and use the free version of Pycharm which seems to have less problems although that is probably a time consuming task for you to setup and switch to,

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if you have `pydevd` installed somewhere in your system and remove it if that's the case? (i.e.: run without debugging `import pydevd` and if you find it remove it from your interpreter).

The PyDev debugger is used in other products (such as PyCharm and Visual Studio), so, my guess is that a non-compatible version is installed somewhere instead of using the version which is shipped along with Eclipse/PyDev.